# Register/Include javascript within RenderingTemplate

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, templates, include, rendering

## Problem description

Is it possible to register (include) javascript within **RenderingTemplate**? (RenderingTemplates are used to render list forms or fields)
By using

```
<SharePoint:RenderingTemplate ID="NewRelatedListItem" runat="server">
  <Template>
    <span id="part1">
      <SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="SPFormFieldAssistant.js" Localizable="false" /> 
      ...
    </span>
    ...
  </Template>
</SharePoint:RenderingTemplate>
```

it couldn't be done - it **didn't** include script at HEAD area, but...:

[Source http://img62.imageshack.us/img62/9826/ss20100324092808.png](http://img62.imageshack.us/img62/9826/ss20100324092808.png)

Is something wrong with my code? Althought script IS at Layouts folder and I checked with Reflector that it uses Layouts folder if Localizable='False'.

I don't want this script to be loaded with every page, but only for forms.

Any ideas on how this could be achieved?

## My idea that is not working...

My first idea was to **add** script **programmatically** with `<% this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("spffa", "/_layouts/SPFormFieldAssistant.js") %>`, but it is not working, as that code evaluation is happening in Render method and i read somwhere that you cannot register client scripts within Render method, but usually is done within PreRender method. Pity

## My second idea that is still not working

I thought i would **create custom UserControl** named RegisterClientScript and there within overriden PreRender method i would add scripts i need with client script manager (this.Page.ClientScript...) but, as with SharePoint:ScriptLink, my control also is rendered as text!
[my control as text http://img693.imageshack.us/img693/3738/ss20100324115826.png](http://img693.imageshack.us/img693/3738/ss20100324115826.png)

How do i overcome this and where's the catch?

Comment: runat=where? should be specified if you need server-side controls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that you can directly add `<script>` tags to template!

```
<script src="/_layouts/SPFormFieldAssistant.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Thank you for the notes however.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are missing the runat. Try this:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="SPFormFieldAssistant.js" Localizable="false" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Aahh, thank you! Doh! But i`v solved this already without using such server controls.

Answer (score 1):

Sometime back I had a Similar requirement. For which I have included the script Register in the CreateChildControls method of the Field Control class.

Comment: Thank you, but i found much simplier solution - it is possible to directly add <script> tags to template.